# Open new editor pane in workspace (handle is missing)

Tags: workspaces

There are a few tutorials ([for example this one](https://youtu.be/StTF1c2Jngs?t=118), screen shots below) which show you can add a new pane to a workspace but in my version of Blender 2.8 (running on Windows 10) I can't recreate this option.  It looks like the handle is missing.  The handle being the little diagonal lines in the top right corner.

[image: handle for new editor in workspace is missing]

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the UI is different?  You can create a new editor pane inside a workspace by clicking and dragging in the tiny dark space between the panes.  See annotated screenshot below.

[image: how to create new editor pane in workspace]