# How to have editor panes in the workspace be different editor types

Tags: workspaces

I am using Blender 2.8 (Windows 10).  I have now been able to create two editor panes in the same workspace ([see this Q/A](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/158963/83475)).  The new editor pane(s) is set to the same editor type as the existing pane.   Trying to change one pane's editor type changes the other pane's editor type.  How can you set them to different editor types?  [A tutorial suggestions this is possible](https://youtu.be/1drRNphACMc?t=246) (screenshots attached).

[image]

Editor panes in my blender seem to be locked to be of the same type.  Changing one type changes the other's type to the same type:
[image: editor pane types can not be changed independently of each other]

Screenshot of splash screen with version:
[image: version of blender as 2.8]

Comment: Hi @AJP, those screen grabs are for v2.78 ... but you say you are using 2.8x ... oh wait ... I see you are comparing what you used to be able to do

Comment: Hi @Merlin thanks so much for checking.  I think I'm using v2.8 (attached another screen shot).  "I see you are comparing what you used to be able to do", um, I didn't mean to say that.  I've only started using blender since Thursday :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok this isn't possible.  What's being show in the video is opening a different Editor Type which is possible.  What the question is asking for is opening the same Editor Type but with a different Editor Mode.  And this isn't possible: perhaps because the contextual interface on the right would be confusing as it would depend on which editor pane you were in.

Comment: Concretely, blender only supports a single context per workspace, so it can only be in one mode at a time.  You can have something else going on in another workspace ( top tabs ) it would seem.