# Can not select object in other collection

Tags: edit-mode, collections, select

I'm using Blender 2.8 (Windows 10).  I have two collections.  One With a plane that I would like to hold a projection of an image I would like to convert into an object.  The other collection with the object I am modelling.  Somehow the wedge object is unselectable and I can only select the plane object.  Trying to access it from the objects list and choosing "select" just results in the image below (but does not allow me to edit it using the "Edit mode" options.

Can not select object in other collection:
[image: can not select object in other collection]

Can kind of selected object in other collection but not really by using the "Select" option.  This does not let you actually edit the object though.
[image: kind of selected object in other collection but not really]

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic gotcha.

If you see this in the 3D viewport ...

[image: Edit Mode]

You're still in *Edit Mode* and although it looks like you've selected another object, you really haven't ... you've added a secondary object to the selection.

Hit the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key to go back to *Object Mode*, then you should be able to select objects normally again.

Alternatively if you want to stay in edit mode but switch objects then you can simply click the *Edit Mesh* toggle in the outliner.

[image: Edit Mesh]

This is a real pain in the -Z, something I hope is addressed in the future.  It catches me out daily.

Comment: Thanks Merlin.  I will mark your answer as correct when the 2 days has past... I'm just writing up my own answer with 3 additional and different ways of doing the same thing.  Thank you so much for your answer though as it has a nice keyboard shortcut!  Any help on this one would be great though: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/158969/83475  I am stuck :)

Answer (score 0):

Notice in the right hand side the word "Plane" is in orange but the "Wedge" is in grey.  If you click the down arrow to the left of "Wedge" and then click the green icon or the text then you can edit the wedge object.  I don't know what the orange triangle icon vs green triangle item means yet.  I also don't know if this is a bug / feature though it's pretty confusing.

Alternatively if you change the editor type to "Object Mode", then click the "Wedge" text or click the wedge object in your scene.  Then change to "Editor Mode" it will then let you edit the wedge object you see (same as [Merlin's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/158975/83475) but without the nice keyboard shortcut)

OR, if you right click "Wedge" text and choose "Select", then change to "Object Mode" and back to "Edit Mode" you can now edit both objects.

Comment: The green triangle is button to *Toggle Edit Mode* for that mesh data.

Comment: The orange triangle is just an icon for a Mesh Object

Comment: "Toggle Edit Mode for that mesh data" -> yes you're right... that's a 4th way of doing it... but only works if the Mesh Object has been opened.  Clicking the Green icon when that Mesh Object is collapsed won't do anything.

Comment: That must have been fixed in v2.81

Comment: @Merlin , you're correct.  Fixed in v2.81.  Apologies for the noise.